# CUDA performance: branching and shared memory

Tags: cuda

I wish to ask two questions on performance. I have been unable to create simple code to illustrate.

Question 1: How expensive is non-divergent branching? In my code it seems that it even goes up as to more then the equivalent of 4 non-fma FLOPS. Note that I am speaking of the BRA PTX code whereby the predicate is already calculated

Question 2: I have been reading a lot about performance of shared memory and some articles like [a Dr Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/208801731) even state that it can be as fast as registers (as far as accessed well). In my code all threads within the warps within the block access the same shared variable. I believe in this case shared memory is accessed in broadcast mode, isn't it? Should it reach the performance of registers in this way? Is there any special things that should be considered to make it work?

EDIT: I have been able to construct some simple code that give more insight for my query

Here it is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "cuComplex.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

__global__ void test()
{
__shared__ int t[1024];
   int v=t[0];
    bool b=(v==-1);
    bool c=(v==-2);
    int myValue=0;
    for (int i=0;i<800;i++)
    {
#if 1
            v=i;
#else
            v=t[i];
#endif

#if 0
            if (b) {
                    printf("abs");
            }
#endif
            if (c)
            {
                    printf ("IT HAPPENED");
                    v=8;
            }
            myValue+=v;

    }
    if (myValue==1000)
            printf ("IT HAPPENED");



}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cudaEvent_t event_start,event_stop;
    float timestamp;
float4  *data;
    // Initialise
    cudaDeviceReset();
    cudaSetDevice(0);
dim3 threadsPerBlock;
dim3 blocks;
 threadsPerBlock.x=32;
 threadsPerBlock.y=32;
 threadsPerBlock.z=1;
 blocks.x=1;
 blocks.y=1000;
 blocks.z=1;
 cudaEventCreate(&event_start);
 cudaEventCreate(&event_stop);
cudaEventRecord(event_start, 0);
test<<<blocks,threadsPerBlock,0>>>();
    cudaEventRecord(event_stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(event_stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&timestamp, event_start, event_stop);
    printf("Calculated in %f", timestamp);
}
```

I am running this code on a GTX680.

Now the results are as follows ..

If run as it is it takes 5.44 ms

If I change the first #if conditional to 0 (which will enable reading from shared memory) it will take 6.02ms.. Not much more but still not enough for me

If I enable the second #if conditional (inserts a branch that will never evaluate to true) the it runs in 9.647040ms. The performance reduction is very big. What is the cause and what can be done?

I have also changed slightly the code to make further checks with shared memory

Instead of

```
__shared__ int t[1024]
```

I did

```
__shared__ int2 t[1024]
```

and wherever I access t[] I just access t[].x. In got a further drop in performance to 10ms..(another 400micro seconds) Why this should happen?

Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Have you determined if your kernel is compute bound or memory bound? Your first question would be most relevant if your kernel is compute bound, while the second wold be most relevant if your kernel is memory bound. You might be getting results that are confusing or hard to reproduce if you're assuming one, while it is the other.

(1) I don't think the cost of a branch has been published. You might be left to determining that experimentally for your architecture. The CUDA Programming Guide does say that there is no "branch prediction and no speculative execution."

(2) You're right that when you access a single 32-bit value in shared memory from all the threads in a warp, the value is broadcast. But my guess would be that accessing a single value from all threads would have the same cost as accessing any combination of values as long as you don't incur any bank conflicts. So you end up with the latency of a single fetch from shared memory. I don't think the number of cycles of latency has been published. It is short enough that it is normally easily hidden.

Comment: Absolutely very confusing I would say. I am trying to produce some good simple code to illustrate the problem.. will come back once hopefully successful

Answer (score 0):

- You need to keep in mind that the compiler is highly optimizing. So if you comment out the branch, you also eliminate the evaluation of the conditional, wether or not you leave it in the source code. Thus a difference of four instructions seems very plausible for your example:

  1. load `-1`,
  2. compare `v` to it (and store result in `b`),
  3. test `b`,
  4. branch,

  although I have not compiled your example and looked at the code (which is what you should do - run `cuobjdump -sass` on your binaries and look at the actual differences in machine code.
- Using the only the `.x` compnent of an `int2` changes the layout in shared memory so that you go from bank conflict free access to a 2-way bank conflict, which causes the slight further slowdown in your example. IIRC the latency of a shared memory access is of the order of 30 cycles, which usually is easily hidden by other threads (as Roger has already mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for the help..I am still digesting all this.. but why are you saying that I created a bank conflict when using the .x component of int2...? all threads are still accessing the same element

Comment: Is I read your example and the description of the changes you made to it before running it, the threads are not accessing the same elements. Post the exact code you are timing, and we can have a look at what is happening.