# Shared memory, branching performance and register count

Tags: cuda

I came across some peculiar performance behaviour when trying out the CUDA `shuffle` instruction. The test kernel below is based on an image processing algorithm which adds input-dependent values to all neighbouring pixels within a square of side `rad`. The output for each block is added in shared memory. If only one thread per warp adds its result to shared memory, the performance is poor (Option 1), whereas on the other hand, if all threads add to shared memory (one thread adds the desired value, the rest just add 0), the execution time drops by 2-3 times (Option 2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#define warpSz 32
#define tileY 32
#define rad 32

__global__ void test(float *out, int pitch)
{
    // Set shared mem to 0
    __shared__ float tile[(warpSz + 2*rad) * (tileY + 2*rad)];
    for (int i = threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x; i<(tileY+2*rad)*(warpSz+2*rad); i+=blockDim.x*blockDim.y) {
        tile[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for (int row=threadIdx.y; row<tileY; row += blockDim.y) {
        // Loop over pixels in neighbourhood
        for (int i=0; i<2*rad+1; ++i) {
            float res = 0.0f;
            int rowStartIdx = (row+i)*(warpSz+2*rad);
            for (int j=0; j<2*rad+1; ++j) {
                res += float(threadIdx.x+row); // Substitute for real calculation

                // Option 1: one thread writes to shared mem
                if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
                    tile[rowStartIdx + j] += res;
                    res = 0.0f;
                }

                //// Option 2: all threads write to shared mem
                //float tmp = 0.0f;
                //if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
                //  tmp = res;
                //  res = 0.0f;
                //}
                //tile[rowStartIdx + threadIdx.x+j] += tmp;

                res = __shfl(res, (threadIdx.x+1) % warpSz);
            }
            res += float(threadIdx.x+row);
            tile[rowStartIdx + threadIdx.x+2*rad] += res;
            __syncthreads();
        }
    }

    // Add result back to global mem
    for (int row=threadIdx.y; row<tileY+2*rad; row+=blockDim.y) {
        for (int col=threadIdx.x; col<warpSz+2*rad; col+=warpSz) {
            int idx = (blockIdx.y*tileY + row)*pitch + blockIdx.x*warpSz + col;
            atomicAdd(out+idx, tile[row*(warpSz+2*rad) + col]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int2 dim = make_int2(512, 512);
    int pitchOut = (((dim.x+2*rad)+warpSz-1) / warpSz) * warpSz;
    int sizeOut = pitchOut*(dim.y+2*rad);
    dim3 gridDim((dim.x+warpSz-1)/warpSz, (dim.y+tileY-1)/tileY, 1);
    float *devOut;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&devOut, sizeOut*sizeof(float));
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaFree(0);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    test<<<gridDim, dim3(warpSz, 8)>>>(devOut, pitchOut);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop);
    cudaFree(devOut);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsedTime << " ms.\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Is this expected behaviour/can anyone explain why this happens?

One thing I have noted is that Option 1 uses only 15 registers, whereas Option 2 uses 37, which seems a big difference to me.

Another is that the if-statement in the innermost loop is converted to explicit `bra` instructions in the PTX code for Option 1, whereas for Option 2 it is converted to two `selp` instructions. Could it be that the explicit branching is behind the 2-3 times slow down similar to what's suspected in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239669/cuda-performance-branching-and-shared-memory)?

There are two reasons why I am reluctant to go for Option 2. First, when profiling the original application it seems to be limited by share memory bandwidth, which indicates that there is potential to increase the performance by having fewer threads accessing it. Second, unless we use the `volatile` keyword, writes to shared memory can be optimised to registers. Since we are only interested in the contribution from last the thread to access each memory location (threadIdx.x == 0), and all others add 0, this is not a problem as long as all changes temporarily located in registers are guaranteed to be written back to shared memory in the same order they were issued. Is this the case though? (This far, both options have produced the exact same result.)

Any thoughts or ideas are much appreciated!

PS. I compile for compute capability 3.0. (However, the `shuffle` instruction is not necessary to demonstrate the behaviour and can be commented out.)

Comment: Thanks for the input Young-Bae. I am aware that if threads execute a write instruction to the same location behaviour is undefined. The same is true, due to write caching, if two threads, even if they are in the same warp, read-modify-write the same location in different instructions. However, here, the first 31 threads read and then, potentially delayed by caching, write back the same result. If the issuing order is maintained for the cached writes this works, otherwise it is undefined. I haven't seen anything in the programming guide about this, does anyone have a reference?

Comment: @jorre What do you mean by "writes to shared memory can be cached" ? As far as I know there is no cache level with access latency smaller than the shared memory.

Comment: @jorre To test why option 2 works better I would suggest monitoring the number of replays due to shared memory bank conflicts. I expect a growth for option 1.

Comment: @Young-Bae I am not sure I follow. I don't think there should be a broadcast: in Option 2, each thread reads (and updates) its unique memory location, given by `tile[rowStartIdx + threadIdx.x+j]` in each iteration (the `+threadIdx.x` and using `blockDim.x` = `warpSz` should ensure this).

Comment: @VAndrei As far as I know, unless shared memory is declared using the `volatile` keyword, [there is no guarantee that a write will be carried out immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331009/when-to-use-volatile-with-shared-cuda-memory). Re bank conflicts: one read-modify-write (one bank) per iteration should be as fast as 32 read-modify-writes (still one bank, I think, in this case), unless there is something else at play here.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread your code. There is indeed no broadcast and no undefined behaviour going on. However as VAndrei said there is no such thing as shared memory write caching, it's just that non-atomic reads and writes may stay in registers if you don't use `volatile` or some memory fence (you want a memory fence instead of `volatile`). But there's no "caching".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed the question to reflect that shared memory writes are not truly cached but that shared memory locations can be optimised into registers. Also, my comment above should read "one read-modify-write (one bank) per iteration should be as fast as 32 read-modify-writes (still one bank each, I think, in this case)"

Comment: What device are you on precisely? What optimization level are you using? I cannot replicate your results on my k20, in debug I get the following:
(109.918ms when commenting out both options)
(154.388ms when using option 1)
(160.49ms when using option 2)
With O3 I get 5.377ms, 10.674ms, 7.592ms respectively. There is a chance of course that the -O3 removed important computations which I've had happen in the past. You should include validation in this code sample when testing to make sure optimization isn't giving you "faster" results at the loss of a correct answer.

Comment: I can confirm both options give the same answer (I edited two minor errors in the code above, neither of which affected the relative performance). N.B. device memory has to be set to zero before comparing. Compiled in Release x64 (no -G flag) and -O2 (although this is only for host code(?)). Option 2 is 2.3 times faster on both my GTX680 and K1100M, can try on K40 too. Although you don't see the exact same ratio, the trend remains: an otherwise "identical" kernel that uses significantly less shared memory bandwidth is considerably slower. Any ideas?